# Can I use predefined styles from Excel in C# COM program?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, heading

I am quite new to writing a program using COM excel API. But I am getting to grips with it but I am having an issue with setting a style for a set range. I would like to use Excels predefined styles both for headings and the charts but I just keep hitting walls. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Range range1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
Range range2 = worksheet.Cells[1, width];
//ChartObjects cObjects = (ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
//ChartObject cObject = cObjects.Add(10, 80, 300, 400);
//cObject.Style.Name = "Style 8";

range = (Range)worksheet.get_Range(range1, range2);
range.Merge(true);
range.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
range.Font.Bold = true;
range.Value2 = "Vendors";
range.Style.Name = "Style 8";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dic)
{
    range = worksheet.get_Range("A2").get_Offset(0, counter);
    range.Value2 = kvp.Key;
    range = worksheet.get_Range("A3").get_Offset(0, counter);
    range.Value2 = kvp.Value;
    counter++;
}

//Chart chart = cObject.Chart;
//range = (Range)worksheet.get_Range(range1, range2);
//chart.SetSourceData(range);
//chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Translink Device Vendors";
```

Comment: What is `dic` What is the loop trying to do?

Comment: dic is a Dictionary<string, int>. The loop goes through each each KeyValuePair that exists in the dictionary and adds the values to the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The problem was the format that I was saving in. I did not know that the .CSV file did not save any styling in the worksheet. I changed the save to an .XLSX file and the styles saved without an issue.